# Django: How to add manager in the manager model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

[image: here is the image]I am new to django and working on a project where admin can assign team to manager. I want to known that how can i attach that model and the manager. i mean manager are those who have is_staff status true and have some special permission that i have made for a manager. and only the name of those person should be shown to the admin whose i_staff status is true and have that special permission. And i have no Idea how can i do this.

here is model of manager and views.

```
def login(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    # print(request.POST)
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        print (user.has_perm('app.edit_task'))
        # return redirect('index')

        if user.is_superuser:
            return redirect('master')

        # elif user.has_perm('app.edit_task'):
        #     return redirect('manager')
        elif user.is_staff:
            return redirect('manager')
        else:
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
        return redirect('login')    
else: 
    return render(request, 'vadash/sign-in.html')
```

here is my model of manager

```
class manager(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
designation = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
class Meta:
    permissions = [
        ("edit_task", "can edit the task"),
    ]

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Create_Team(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
company_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
address = models.CharField(max_length= 1000)
state = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
city = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
pin_code = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
email = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
company_description = models.TextField()
work_description = models.TextField()
team_member = models.CharField(max_length= 1000)
remark = models.TextField(blank=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length= 30)
managers = models.ForeignKey('manager', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

here is the admin dashboard where admin can do a certain things:

```
 def admin_team_detail(request):
   obj= Create_Team.objects.all()
  print(request.method)
  if request.method == 'POST':
# First, you should retrieve the team instance you want to update
    team = Create_Team.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('id'))
    print(request.POST)
    # Next, you update the status
    # if request.POST.get('accept'):
    #     team.status = request.POST.get('accept')
    #     team.save()

    # else:
    #     team.status = request.POST.get('reject')
    #     team.save()

    if request.POST.get('status'):
        team.status = request.POST.get('status')
        team.save()
return render(request, "admin/team-details.html", {"object": obj})


 def accept(request):
  obj= Create_Team.objects.filter(status='Accept') 
 managers = manager.objects.all()
 if request.method == 'POST':
   createteam = Create_Team()
   createteam_id = int(request.POST.get('team', 1))
   manager_id = int(request.POST.get('manager', 1))
   createteam = Create_Team.objects.get(pk=createteam_id)
   createteam.manager = manager.objects.get(pk=manager_id)
   createteam.save()

  return render(request, "admin/accept.html", {"object": obj,  "managers": managers})

def reject(request):
 obj= Create_Team.objects.filter(status='Reject') 
 return render(request, "admin/reject.html", {"object": obj})
```

I want that users who have is_staff status true and have that permission only that users should be shown in the admin.

Comment: which view in admin? and how does `manager` model relate to `user` if it's only 2 char fields?

Comment: it is attached to team as admin can assign team to manager.

Comment: if the user is admin then it render the master page if the user is the manager then it will render the the admin page

Comment: i will assign some more views.

Comment: you can see my edits

Comment: it's difficult to understand what you want exactly. but you probably want to restrict access to your views for certain users, and since you already assign users a specific permission, have a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator)

Comment: i want that users who have certain permission that is given in the manager only those users will be shown to the admin at the dashboard so he can assign team to those users only i will add an image so that u understand better and give me the answer

Comment: but nowhere in your models are there `User`s involved. A `Manager` doesn't have permissions in your models. and your `Create_Team` model (bad name by the way, why not just `Team`) doesn't allow you to "assign a user" as you say, because it's not related to `User`.

Comment: @SahilSharma look into changing `Manager` to extend default `User` like in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). That way you can attach custom fields to default users and they can use built-in permissions system.

Comment: @dirkgroten can you tell me how can i do this with code

Comment: @SahilSharma sorry I can't because I still don't fully understand your question. Maybe ask a native English speaker to help you formulate your question in precise wordings. Your wording makes it too difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: wait i can explain you in better way simply i want that whenever admin assign a team to manager then that team should be displayed on that manager's dashboard

Comment: so i have made a special permission to manager i.e. if a user have that permission then that user can login as manager and the name of that user can be displayed in to the admin

Comment: Firstly can you tell me the way i have made manager is right or not if it is wrong then how can i improve myself